# How to work with ModelForm and ModelFormSet

Tags: python, django, django-formwizard

I just want some clarification. I'm working through the [Django Form Wizard documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)

In the documentation it talks about the Form Wizard being able to 'work' with ModelForm and ModelFormSet. I want clarification on what this means. Does it mean that the Form Wizard can save the post data of a form straight to the database via the model?

I'm passing the instance of a model as an argument in the instance_dict parameter without success. When I submit the form the form gets processed but nothing is sent to the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not saving the form information automatically!

Usually you need to process the form in your view. A `ModelForm` is basically just a helper to make model instance edting/creating easier and of course more native for your frontend. So here something you usually would do in your view (in short):

```
form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
if form.is_valid():   # checks of the form and its fields validate
    form.save()
# else you can do something else, show the validation errors for example
```

For more details you should check the [docs about how to work with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and the [ModelForm documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). Starting direclty with the FormWizard wasn't maybe such a good idea. :)